# Why 1st print statement did'nt print RID?

Tags: java, string

```
//Why 1st print statement did'nt print `RID`?

class StringDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char s[] = {'a', 'b'};
        int s1[] = {1, 3, 4, 5};
        System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println(s + "   " + s1);
    }
}
```

Comment: @KevinEsche I think OP meant to ask why something like this **didn't** happen for the first array (`s`).

Comment: What do you mean by `RID`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `System.out.println(s);` print the char[] values because `PrintStream`has a method to print the `char[]`

```
public void println(char x[]) {
```

If you try to print the object  then it will print the hexString of objects hashcode.

```
 public void println(Object x) {
        String s = String.valueOf(x);
```